# current_app application context in flask. Get working instance of flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, applicationcontext

I am trying to setup simple flask application to perceive `app_context()` feature.

This is my code:

```
# config.py
UPDATE_PERIOD = 100.0
```

---

```
# init.py
from flask import Flask
import config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

---

```
# ex.py
from flask import current_app 

from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

with app.app_context() as app:
    print(current_app.config['DEBUG'])
    print(current_app.config['UPDATE_PERIOD'])
```

Now, I am running my init.py:

```
python3 init.py

* Serving Flask app "init" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 666-659-182
```

which is okay, how it should be.
Here I expect that `app.config['DEBUG'] = True` and `app.config['UPDATE_PERIOD'] = 100.0`

And I am trying to extract this vars in `ex.py`.

The problem is: when I execute: `python3 ex.py` I expect this:

```
True
100.0
```

but eventually I am getting this:

```
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(current_app.config['UPDATE_PERIOD'])
KeyError: 'UPDATE_PERIOD'
```

so I cannot get how app_context() feature is working whereas I think I am doing the same things as written in [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.app_context).

There is an option to import in `ex.py`:

```
from init import app
```

but I want to **get working instance** without complex import since my application is quite big.

Can anyone please help me with this..?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to access variables from one python process by running a separate process? The app context is not an IPC mechanism and each process will have their own totally separate variables. The app context is used to store data within a single app, and it's not even shared between threads.